# Are perks limited per prestige?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

I got Freddy to level 50 prestige 1 and I was going to farm bloodpoints with him but I noticed that I'm missing a good perk for farming with Freddy, Distressing. I kept upgrading his bloodweb but now there are no perks showing up.

Do I need to fully prestige Freddy to get all of the perks I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

There are 63 Perks for Killer and 71 Perks for Survivor in the game.

The only thing you have to watch out for is that 3 perks are specific for each survivors/killers and can only be unlocked one at a time at level 30/35/40.
**Distressing** is not one of those perks and therefore it's always available for every killer.

Beside that you can pretty much unlock every other perk from the get go and it's only a matter of luck to get the perk you are looking for fast. 
Prestige will only grand you a slightly higher chance to get higher ranked add-on and offerings and it will give you one part of the prestige cosmetic set but it will not unlock any more perks.

Recently they changed the blood web so that you get 3 perks at higher levels (i believe it starts at level 30), of which you can then buy 2 most of the time.

**tl;dr**

So either, you already have the perk and did overlook it in your Loadout, which is possible by the sheer amount of perks, **or** you can try to buy the entire current blood web and since it might very well be a glitch and the next blood web will have perks for your purchase again.

Maybe you even overlooked a perk you could buy on the current blood web. That happened to me once or twice, so it's another possibility.

Comment: Must be a glitch then, I've leveled it up multiple times past when the perks stopped snowing up and the entity eats Add Ons and Offerings showing that there are no perks. Plus I've looked for the perk about 10 times over so I doubt I'm looking over it.

Comment: At least you can still prestige in hopes that it shows up at prestige 1 but i would also file an bug report towards behavior so they can (hopefully) fix that problem.

Comment: 63 Perks means 189 level if you got all the perks unlocked, well with the new change which gives you 2 perks per level it won't be that long anymore but still, it takes a while. I would rather just collect points for going prestige and only focus on leveling up when you have prestige 3.

Comment: It's 0-1 perk per bloodweb at level 1-9, 1-2 perks per bloodweb at 10-24, 2 perks per bloodweb at 25-39, 3 perks per bloodweb at 40-49, and 4 perks per bloodweb at 50+.  Bear in mind that the entity will take a perk every time you take one, so you can only get max 1 per level at levels 1-39 and max 2 per level at levels 40+.